# Python cannot connect to MySQL db

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, sqlite, flask

I use MySQL database to create a sqlite3 db. I don't know is it work. If use MySQL to create sqlite3 db is not work, please tell me. Thank you.

And I code  "conn = sqlite3.connect('MyDatabaseEndPoint')" in config.py to connect to MySQL db. But the db has username and password. Please tell me how should I insert the code then the website can connect to MySQL db?

```
   import os
    import sqlite3
    from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OID, AUTH_REMOTE_USER, AUTH_DB, AUTH_LDAP, AUTH_OAUTH
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    # Your App secret key
    SECRET_KEY = '\2\1thisismyscretkey\1\2\e\y\y\h'

    # The SQLAlchemy connection string.
    conn = sqlite3.connect('MyDatabaseEndPoint')
```

Answer (score 0):

No, MySQL cannot create a sqlite3 database because those are two different database management systems with different datatypes, tools, et cetera. For now, forget about MySQL and just use sqlite3 to learn more. It looks like you are trying to build a flask-sqlalchemy app (given your imports and comments in the code above). While these are easy to get up and running with if you have some familiarity with python, if you have no understanding of databases then constructing web apps is not your best bet for a first, second, or even third project. Get a better foundation in databases before you launch an app or it will be a very frustrating process.

Connecting to a sqlite3 database using the python DB API looks like this:

```
# create connection
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("databasename.db")

# create a cursor object
c = connection.cursor()

# execute a query
c.execute("sql query")

# commit the changes
connection.commit()

# close the connection
connection.close()
```

Please read the Python DB API docs for more answers. I recommend using the DB API at first so that you can understand SQL a little more before moving onto sqlalchemy (ORMs are great, but you really should have some understanding of SQL before using them).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html